# Firestore FieldValue.delete not actually deleting the field

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I built a simple follow/unfollow toggle button; on clicking follow, the code adds a field with the user to a document in Firestore. On clicking unfollow, my code is supposed to delete this field, but for some reason the field is not actually deleted when I check the Firestore database. It prints "document successfully updated", but is not actually deleted when I check the database. Thanks in advance!

```
@IBAction func followTapped (_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if toggleState == 1 {

        toggleState = 2
        followButton.setImage(imgUnfollow, for: .normal )
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let email = userRef

        db.collection("users").document("\(email)").collection("following").document("people").setData(["\(selectedUser)":"\(selectedUser)"], merge: true)
        
       } else {

        toggleState = 1
        followButton.setImage(imgFollow, for: .normal )
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let email = userRef
        
        db.collection("users").document("\(email)").collection("following").document("people").updateData(["\(selectedUser)": FieldValue.delete()]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully updated")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, could it be my Firestore rules? reading and writing works fine but like I said above, deleting doesn't. Also I'm not worried about security for now so I just want my Firestore rules to work. here are my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
         allow read, write, update: if
              request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 4);
         allow delete: if
              request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 4);
              
        }
      }
    }
```

Here are a couple screenshots of my Database:
[Database1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybZYV.png)
[Database2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i96P.png)

Comment: If there is no typos this looks in accordance with [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections). Don't know about Swift and usage of backslash, can you try without it and brackets?

Comment: @EmilGi thanks for the comment! the brackets are necessary otherwise a bunch of errors are thrown. selected user in "backslash(selectedUser)" is a variable that can change so I need to have that backslash() present. Although I did try it with an existing field value without the backslash() and it does the same thing unfortunately

Comment: Hard to tell what can be wrong then, can you also provide screenshot of your db?

Comment: @EmilGi I just added a couple screenshots of my db to the description... I really appreciate the help

Comment: You need to check if replaced string values are matching ones in your database. Also try hardcoding these values and see if the field gets deleted.

Comment: For anyone that has the same issue, the firebase documentation is incorrect-- in order to get this code working I had to use "setData" with "merge: true" instead of using "updateData".